Does the synchronized getter method see the fully or partially initialized object?
Suppose I have the next class:
class Point {

    int x, y, z;

    public Point(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
        this.z = z;  
    }

    public **synchronized** int getSum() {
        return x + y + z;
    }
}

Is it possible to have a partially initialized fields in the synchronized getSum() method?

No guarantee, you should provide a method verification.

@RomanC No guarantee. Thanks for your answer!

Technically speaking,  your code example would never print anything because it contains no print call, and if you added a print call, it would only ever show getSum returning 6 because your example never creates any new thread. In general, you'll get better quality answers here if you show complete code examples.

No. You need to make your fields final to guarantee that class is fully initialized before sharing with other thread.
Alternatively you can put invoking of constructor inside synchronized block. Share it outside said block.

No guarantee. thanks for your answer!

If the sharing happens after the constructor completes, other threads will only see the state as initialized by the constructor. Yes, in theory it is not guaranteed (see the link pebble unit posted, but as far as I know, in practice that wouldn't happen in practice).

@MarkRotteveel But it is possible to share reference before the constructor completes..

Not if you don't share it from the constructor, and if you use a safe method of publication; which you should do anyway when sharing something with multiple threads.

@MarkRotteveel I'm agree about safe method of publication. But what if the reference doesn't escape the constructor and I'm not using the volotile or final fields. Is it possible to have partially initialized fields?

@Sincerely You mean possible in theoretical sense (there is no guarantee of opposite) or in practical (there is a way to reproduce it)?

Synchronized provides both atomicity and visibility so sum should always be consistent.

But it's also possible to have a partially initialized object after publishing the reference..

@Sincerely But that doesn't happen in the code you show. Partial publication can basically only happen if the constructor calls a method passing itself (this).

@MarkRotteveel Thanks for your comment!  But what about reordering. The first operation is init the x field, then the second one is assign the reference to p?

@Sincerely If you're concerned about that, you should make p a volatile field. But your toy example doesn't have such concerns. And generally, if you write thread-safe code, publication to other threads happens in a way that would (should) establish a happens-before anyway, and then that concern is already addressed.

@MarkRotteveel Isn't it possible that constructor is called after assignment of the reference (by reordering)? That would not break single-threaded semantic but the multi-threaded one. Wasn't it the point of the post?

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Only if you publish to other threads in a non-threadsafe manner to begin with.

I am not sure I understand the problem, looks like references should be atomic in this case to avoid in consistent behaviour.
